# invalid operation: (operator - not defined on string)

Tags: go, operator-keyword

```
arrayAll := []string{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"}

x := p[arrayAll[i]-"a"]
```

go does not support operators "-"，
so how can I get the index of array：arrayAll[i]-"a"

Comment: What is it you want exactly? Get the index of an element in the array (which is a slice in your case)? Or remove an element from the array/slice?

Comment: you have to ask a more detailed question

Answer (score 2):

How would you define operator `-` on strings? What result would you expect after calling `"Hello"-"World"`?

Are you trying to operate on single characters? This is well defined and you can probably expect `'c'-'a'` to equal `2` indeed. Consider:

```
arrayAll := []byte{'a', 'b', 'c'} (or simply "abc")
x := p[arrayAll[2] - 'a']
```

One way or another you most probably don't want to subtract strings, but integer representations of characters.